# How to add JSON properties runtime c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My JSON looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "test.txt",
    "fields": {
      "_str.application": [ "Text File" ],
      "_str.body": [ "asdsadasd" ],
      "_str.mimetype": [ "text/plain" ]
    }
  }
]
```

How can I add new properties into `fields` from C# code?

I have already prepared for `Serialization`

```
public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("_str.application")]
    public IList<string> _str_application { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_str.body")]
    public IList<string> _str_body { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_str.mimetype")]
    public IList<string> _str_mimetype { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}
```

I need to add new `JsonProperty`s into `Fields` at runtime.

Comment: It's a little difficult because you are using `JsonProperty` attribute. But adding for adding runtime properties you need to use `ExpandoObject` which is a `dynamic` type. `var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
x.Add("NewProp", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.NET for deserialize as dynamic and adding fields in runtime, then serialize again:

```
string jsonText = "{'Bar':'something'}";
dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
foo.Dynamic="field";
jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```